# Run a R script in Filezilla

Tags: r, filezilla

I wonder if its possible run a R script in filezilla.

My purpose is run a random forest analysis for several weeks and I would like use this server to run this script and get the results when it finish.

I have acces to a remote server.

Regards.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you really referring to the FTP application FileZilla or is this a typo? If you're really referring to FileZilla, the answer is no. Public and external (S)FTP servers may support few server-side shell commands (see e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/821892/filezilla-can-i-run-a-remote-shell-command-via-filezilla-client)), but running R would require a server-wide R installation, infrastructure/scheduler to manage compute jobs etc. That's (usually) not what an FTP server is meant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP and SFTP aren't normally used to kick off (initiate, run) programs. Having said that... I do something vaguely similar, wherein I send R plots to Raspberry Pi IoT smartscreens over FTP/SFTP.

My project is described [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/IoT-Data-Science-PiNet/). If this won't work for yours then just please provide additional details and I'll help edit this with into an appropriate FileZilla adaptation.

Here's what I do in general for my tasks like this:

1. Setup a task / cron job / macro, etc to look for a file on Computer A
2. Write a little SFTP script [like this](https://github.com/hack-r/IoT_Data_Science_Pi_Net/blob/master/R/scp_pi_push0.txt) and call it within your code on Computer B
3. The code transfers the file and the CRON job or Windows task or whatever program that is always looking for that file to change

There are any number minor variations of this appropriate to different use cases.

In your case it sounds like your CRON job on the server (Computer A) should always be looking for changes to the input data set (?) being uploaded to it by your laptop (Computer B) and once it's done your R script will call some code that's like my 2nd link above, which sends the output data to you over FTP/SFTP.

Your R script could be something like this (arbitrary Machine Learning, followed by a call to FTP/SFTP/SCP).

**Machine_learning_code.R**

```
###############################
# Random Forest SFTP Example  #
###############################

# You would run this on the server
library(RRF)  
set.seed(1)

# What's RRF do better than randomForest? 
# See hack-r.com for a tutorial

# Only the 1st and last features are truly useful
X <- matrix(runif(50*50), ncol=50)
class <- (X[,1])^2 + (X[,50])^2  
class[class>median(class)]  <- 1;
class[class<=median(class)] <- 0

# Ordinary random forest
rf <- RRF(X,as.factor(class), flagReg = 0)

predictions <- predict(rf)

write.csv(predictions)

msg <- system("WinSCP.com /script=..//code//win_scp_pi_push1", intern=T)
print(msg)
```

On the same computer you should also run the script (`win_scp_pi_push1`) in the example like the one I linked to above on GitHub.

I used WinSCP, but FileZilla also supports the command line:

https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client)

Comment: Thanks, finally I could do this with a remote ssh server, its a little slow but works fine.I use FileZilla to transfer data and scripts.

Comment: Interesting answer! +1

Comment: Do you know how stop a script/process, when your data have error and should change  it and stop it??

Comment: @RodrigoBadilla `tryCatch` in R. Also ping me in Stack Overflow chat if you have more questions and/or feel free to ask further questions on [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/IoT-Data-Science-PiNet) since it may be too broad for Stack Overflow. I think you should also share your project there, so we can learn from you.